# how to highlight current click menu items in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is My menu showing file, I need only highlighted current clickable menu item. currently active class item is highlighted

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li style="margin-left:20px;">

            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> @ {{ Auth::user()->name }}</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">PREGO<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Edit Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route('projects.index') }}">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route('collaborators.form', $project)}}">Collaborators</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todos</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class=""><a href="">Account</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="">Help</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

how can do this?

Comment: `I need only highlighted current clickable menu item` it's unclear, could you explain better?

Comment: Give your `li`'s a class then pass the clicked one as parameter and add conditions...

Comment: that means simply I need highlight current menu item @JeremyThille

Comment: I nees some code support @ZakariaAcharki

Comment: no any idea here

Answer (score 0):

```css
.active a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it is only highlight active class

Comment: I need highlight My current menu item as a example when I visit home need highlight home menu and when I visit contact need highlight contact